# How to make ascending order in pivot column in sql

Tags: sql-server

I need to get report for every hour in each system. I have get all the data using pivot. But In my column not order by ascending.

My code is here:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(hour) + ',' FROM (select distinct DATEPART(hh, BillDate) AS hour from Bill_Entry WHERE BillDate >= '6/10/2018 12:00:00' AND BillDate < '7/10/2018 12:00:00' ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    SELECT Remarks, DATEPART(hh, BillDate) AS hour, sum(cast(GrandTotal as int)) as Total
FROM Bill_Entry  WHERE BillDate >=  ''6/10/2018 12:00:00''  AND BillDate <=  ''7/10/2018 12:00:00''

GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, BillDate),Remarks 

) src
pivot 
(
    max(Total) for hour in (' + @cols + ')
) piv order by Len(Remarks), Remarks'

execute(@query)
```

and my output was like this:

[image]

Here My column was not in ascending order.
I need Column like as

8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 ......

Answer (score 1):

You should make the following changes

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + 
            QUOTENAME(hour) + 
            ',' 
            FROM (
            select distinct DATEPART(hh, BillDate) AS hour 
            from Bill_Entry 
            WHERE BillDate >= '6/10/2018 12:00:00' 
            AND BillDate < '7/10/2018 12:00:00' 
            ) as tmp
            ORDER BY DATEPART(hh, BillDate) ASC
            -- the above order by line will solve your issue
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    SELECT Remarks, DATEPART(hh, BillDate) AS hour, sum(cast(GrandTotal as int)) as Total
FROM Bill_Entry  WHERE BillDate >=  ''6/10/2018 12:00:00''  AND BillDate <=  ''7/10/2018 12:00:00''

GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, BillDate),Remarks 

) src
pivot 
(
    max(Total) for hour in (' + @cols + ')
) piv order by Len(Remarks), Remarks'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: @Hisanth Here's hoping you'll break your a ZERO percent ACCEPT rate.   Seriously, how hard is it to CLICK the check to show your appreciation?   +1